# Go project structure - Best practice

Tags: go, project

I need to create GO project (first time) for production, I searched on web for best practices and found the following

https://github.com/golang-standards/project-layout

For this I've two main questions.

1. I see that most of go projects logic is inside the main function, but in case I need some utils folder with files there, where should I put it ?
   I don't want that the main function will be mass of 500 or more lines of code
2. In our company the projects should be build like following

   ```
   myproj
     |-src
       |-cmd
       |  |-main.go
       |-utils
       |-vendor
   ```

Our company project build as above structure i.e. the project files is under the `src` folder, is it right? (can we have issue in the future with this structure type).

I was able to compile this project in our landscape but since everything is under `src` I'm not sure.

Comment: `Can we have issues in the future with this structure?` Of course you can. As with literally every other structure. There's no such thing as a "perfect structure." Every design decision, in every domain, has pros and cons. There is no "one right answer." If there were, nobody would ever ask this question, because the answer would be obvious.

Comment: @Flimzy - Ok...and for utils where I should put it ? is it OK under the src folder ?

Comment: [This](https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1) is a good reference.

Comment: There is no right answer.  Possible answers range from "You should never have 'utils'" to anywhere you like.

Comment: @Flimzy - You are rellay helping here :(

Comment: Your question is off-topic here. You won't likely get help here.

Comment: @Flimzy - Ok so if I've question like this where should I put it? this can help...

Comment: Opinion-based questions like this don't belong on stack overflow at all. Maybe on the go-nuts mailing list.

Comment: Split the whole into packages on sensible package boundaries so that inter-package cohesion is high. It does not matter how you lay out these packages in the filesystem.

Comment: @Volker - Thank you very much , what does it mean `Split the whole into packages on sensible package boundaries` can you please provide it as answer with example, and i'll close the question. thanks again.

Comment: No I cannot. This is much to broad. What logically belongs together goes into one package. This might be a lot of code or not much. Take a look at some OSS projects.

Comment: Following the directory structure in the link has some advantages. Those directories have some tooling semantics. For example if a package from `internal/...` be imported in another _project_, compiler will show an error. And that's the structure that is used in many standard Go packages and by the community. Yet you can have customized structure beside that one, too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

based on https://github.com/anacrolix/torrent

```
GOPATH
  |-src
    |-projectA
      |-cmd (of projectA)
        |-cmdA
          |-main.go
        |-cmdB
          |-main.go
      |-vendor
      |-pkg lib
      |-pkg libB
    |-projectB
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, 1. if I've utils/helpers for projectA where I should put it ? 2. my project path is like following is it fine ?  (mac) `/Users/i122345/go/src/myapp/cmd/main.go` does it fit your proposed structure ?

Comment: 1. assuming only projectA uses it, `/Users/i122345/go/src/myapp/utils/helpers.go` 2. with a cmd at `/Users/i122345/go/src/myapp/cmd/main` the produced binary, after go install, located in GOPATH/bin, will be named `main`, because it is the folder name. to clarify the code of the binary would be at `/Users/i122345/go/src/myapp/cmd/main/main.go`

Answer (score 2):

Following is go project structure I have used for go projects

```
my-project
     |-> api
     |-> api_test
     |-> controllers
     |-> controllers_test
     |-> models
     |-> routes
     |-> server
     |-> vendor
     |main.go
     |Readme.txt
```

Find more about go project structure

https://golang.org/doc/code.html

Comment: just to avoid confusion both structure proposed are valid and works. It all depends on what you feel is the best for your project. Personally, i started with nisal structure, later i switched to the historical layout with sub cmd folder.

Comment: @mh-cbon thanks for the comment